# NodeJS authentication function rewrite with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I will post both of the modules, some of the code in them may be "irrelevant" for the main concern here, which is **Security.prototype.authenticate()**. Nevertheless, comments are welcome about all of the code.

Security.prototype.authenticate() is a controller for a /login API-endpoint.

**security.js**

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var config = require('./config');
var db = require('./db');

function Security() {}

function _verifyPassword(password, hash, salt) {
    var newHash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).update(salt).digest("hex");
    return newHash === hash;
}

function _generateToken(username, secret, expiration) {
    var token = jwt.sign(username, secret, { expiresInMinutes: expiration });
    return { token: token };
}

Security.prototype = {

    tokenCheck: function(req, res) {

        jwt.verify(req.body.token, config.security.secret, function (err, decoded) {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send("Token invalid or expired");
            }

            res.json({ username: decoded });

        });

    },

    authenticate: function(req, res) {

        if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
            return res.status(400).send("Username and/or password field empty");
        }

        Promise.using(db.getConnection(), function(connection) {

            return connection.queryAsync("SELECT password_hash, password_salt FROM users WHERE email = ? AND admin = 1", req.body.username)
                .then(function(rows) {

                    connection.release();

                    if ( rows[0].length === 1 ) {
                        return rows[0][0];
                    } else {
                        throw new Error("Username not found");
                    }

            }).then(function(user) {

                    if ( !_verifyPassword(req.body.password, user.password_hash, user.password_salt) ) {
                        throw new Error("Incorrect password");
                    }

                    res.json({
                        token: _generateToken(req.body.username, config.security.secret, config.security.expiration),
                        username: req.body.username
                    });

            });

        }).error(function(e) {
            res.status(400).send("Database error");
        }).catch(Error, function(e) {
            res.status(400).send(e.message);
        });

    }

};

module.exports = new Security();
```

**db.js**

```
'use strict';

var config = require('./config');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mysql = require('mysql');
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);

function DB() {
    this._pool = _createPool();
}

function _createPool() {

    return mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: config.database.connectionLimit,
        host: config.database.host,
        user: config.database.username,
        password: config.database.password,
        database: config.database.database,
        debug: config.database.debug
    });

}

DB.prototype = {

    getConnection: function() {
        return this._pool.getConnectionAsync();
    }

};

module.exports = new DB();
```

My concerns are any possible anti-patterns that are visible here. I just got rid of one problem with this function, which was nested callbacks, by implementing promises. However, my knowledge of Bluebird is limited to the last ~12 hours. I have used promises before, but not a lot. Also, as I said, comments on the rest of the code are also welcome.